# How to generate a random selection from SQL DB to a listbox using vb.net

Tags: vb.net, gridview, listbox

I am trying to write a program that will allow a user to generate a random list of names.  I have a gridview of names from a SQL Db when the form launches.  Is it possible to generate a random list from the names in the gridview or does that have to come from another Sql Connection string and reference different parameters?  I was trying to display random names from the gridview to a listbox.  Thank you.

Here is the code that I have been trying to experiment with:

```
Private Sub btnDraw_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnDraw.Click

    Dim listCount As Integer
    Dim i As Integer = 0
    Dim rnd As New Random
    Dim listselection As Integer

    listCount = grdEmployees.
    Do While i < CInt(grdEmployees.Text)

    'randomize selection
    listselection = rnd.Next(0, grdEmployees.Items.Count)
    lstSelected.Items.Add(grdEmployees.Items(listselection))
    grdEmployees.Items.RemoveAt(listselection)

    'increment i
    i += 1

    Loop

    txtQuantity.Text = String.Empty  'Clears box after entry

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do it through your SQL query:

SELECT TOP 25 SomeField FROM SomeTable ORDER BY RAND()

Or through your managed code. Which is best depends on the size of the table and where you want the sorting to be done. If you prefer to sort on the server, or locally.

Comment: I understand what you are saying, however, I don't understand how you could do it with two Fields.  I would need to produce Last and First names.  Thank you for your time.

Comment: SELECT TOP 25 FirstName, LastName FROM SomeTable ORDER BY RAND()

Comment: I attempted the above using a Table adapter with no success.  I also found other research that suggests using LIMIT.  It does not recognize Limit when I try to enter the SQL statement.

Comment: Are you using MS SQL Server or another DBMS?

Comment: After checking, RAND() only returns a single random value for the whole SELECT statement. Instead, try this:

SELECT TOP 25 FirstName, LastName FROM SomeTable ORDER BY ABS(CAST(CAST(NEWID() AS VARBINARY) AS INTEGER))